# How many possible groups of 4 can you create from 9 people?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm fairly sure I know how to solve this through combination:

$ \frac{9!}{4!5!} = 126 $

But how do I go about solving this using the product or sum rule?

When I try using the product rule I get $9*8*7*6 = 3024$ possible groups, which seems wrong. Is it that I'm overcounting in some way and would have to divide it by 4! to resolve the issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The order of people in the group doesn't matter so just take $\frac{9*8*7*6}{4!}$

Comment: Ok, I thought so-- I just wanted to confirm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just expand your factorials; this will give you the product rule. Combinatorics is simply a way to represent product rule.

Answer (score 0):

Permutation:$P_k^N=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$,

The combination is a combination of n things taken k at a time without repetition.
:$C_k^n=\frac{P_k^n}{k!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

The way to think about the difference here is that the numbers are chosen in no order, so if you take away the number of ways that you can sort them, you get something like:$C_k^n=\frac{P_k^n}{k!}$

Like this problem:$C_4^9=\frac{9!}{4!5!}=\frac{9*8*7*6*5!}{4!5!}=\frac{9*8*7*6}{4!}=126$ so this is why 5! go away, and we still need to divide by 4!